# How to fix EONENT npm install error for ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I bought a Firebase food order app (ionic). I am actually blocked on a problem :
(I have node js, npm, ionic [lastest versions installed]). I am trying to "npm install" in the app folder, to be able after to deploy the app on my local host but I have this error :

```html
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\Utilisateur\\Documents\\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\\customer\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\Utilisateur\\Documents\\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\\customer\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\Utilisateur\\Documents\\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\\customer\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\Utilisateur\\Documents\\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\\customer\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\Utilisateur\\Documents\\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\\customer\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\Utilisateur\\Documents\\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\\customer\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Utilisateur\\Documents\\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\\customer\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\successdt-ion_restaurant_admin-d763ffe150ec\customer\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-29T10_49_55_470Z-debug.log
```

I am trying since a day to fix this error doing all this :
- reinstall all the modules
- install python 
- npm init 
and severals little things but with no fixing way.

I am beginning in this, thank's for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

try to run this as administrator

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```